# Is there any good choice of Wifi-Transfer(OTA) kit for iOS?(Like cocoawebresource)

Tags: ios, wifi, over-the-air

I have tried cocoawebresource(which is based on cocoahttpserver). It's quite functional , but I wonder is there any other better choice?